# How to properly instantiate an object in one container and store a shared_ptr to it in a separate container?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, smart-pointers

Suppose we have a struct or class that stores some data:

```
struct Foo
{
    int bar;
}
```

Suppose also that I'd like to store two separate vectors; one that contains the actual instances of `Foo`, and a vector of `shared_ptr` that would allow me to access that data arbitrarily:

```
std::vector<Foo> data; // Where the data actually is

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> ptr_data; // A set of pointers to the elements in data
```

**How would I go about inserting an element into the `data` vector and then adding a corresponding `shared_ptr` that points to that element?** I want the only copy of the actual data to exist in the `data` vector.

I don't believe I can use `make_shared`, as I can't seem to find any documentation on how to control *where* the data is stored. And shouldn't the anonymous data be collected as the function goes out of scope?

```
void addDataToVectors() 
{
    ptr_data.push_back(std::make_shared<Foo>( 20 )); // Can I put this into the data vector?
    // And shouldn't the data disappear as soon as this function ends?
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
void addDataToVectors() 
{
    data.push_back({ 20 }); // Add the instance to data
    // Attempt to create a shared pointer from the last address in data
    ptr_data.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Foo>(&data.back())); 
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. The addition of the first set of data and its pointer is correct, but every subsequent `push_back` in the `ptr_data` vector seems to corrupt all entries except the last. Something is clearly wrong with this method, and it feels hacky to begin with.

What is the proper way to do this for a STL container?

Comment: There is no proper way to do anything like that. Neither `std::vector`, nor `std::shared_ptr` work the way you think they work. shared_ptr does not point to any object that's stored in any other container. The whole reason for shared_ptr's existence is that it ***owns*** the object, and is ***completely responsible*** for deleting it. The whole reason for containers is to do the same, but in different ways. Add to this is the fact that vectors can reallocate and move their contents, and you have a completely illogical situation here. Pick one, a container or shared_ptr, but not both.

Comment: You can either have two containers of shared pointers to the same objects or two shared pointers to the same container objects.

Comment: Hmm, that's troubling. I'm trying to create a spatial hashing implementation, and I figured it would be more efficient to store only the pointers within it; that way I wouldn't have to constantly copy and move the data around within the hashmap, I could store them in a separate list and access them via the hashmap instead, as their positions change very frequently. Is this idea malformed, or is it just that there is no logical reason to perform it with both the container and shared_ptr simultaneously?

Comment: An object can only have one owner (or shared owner) so that it only gets deleted once when its owner is deleted. Containers own their objects so you can't then give those same objects another owner. Can you use a vector of raw pointers? As long as you can guarantee the raw pointers will never be used after the vector of objects is destroyed that would be fine. Also you can't change the contents of the vector of ints as that would invalidate your raw pointers.

Comment: Raw pointers might work, although I was hoping to keep the vector where the entities are stored dynamic as well, so I can add and remove as necessary. Perhaps I could pre-allocate a fixed size and limit the amount of entities to within that size? Though there's not much reason to use a vector at that point aside from convenience.
Although, I though the shared_ptr allowed for multiple 'owners', as only when all references to the data are removed does the object destruct. Does shared_ptr have a 'master' instance that controls all other instances, or am I off the deep end?

Comment: If you use `shared_ptr`s then both vectors need to contain `shared_ptr`s to the same `Foo`s. If you use raw pointers then every time you add a `Foo` you need to check if the vector reallocated and if it did, rebuild your raw pointer vector.

Comment: An alternative is to forget pointers and store the indexes as in `std::vector<std::size_t> idx_data;`

Comment: @Galik, I think I'm starting to get it now. The vector doesn't really "contain" the data as much as it just manages it; its all allocated to somewhat random places in memory, the vector just keeps track of where, which is why having two managers is bad. By changing the data vector to also store `shared_ptr`s, I can store all of the data in a consecutive list for easy iteration if I need to perform a set of calculations across all entries, and I can use the other container (the hashmap) for selecting elements within a particular region. This would satisfy my program's requirements. Big thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `shared_ptr` does **not** mean "points to an object managed by someone else." A `shared_ptr` means "points to an object that will be deleted when the last `shared_ptr` to it is gone." A `vector` owns its elements. A `shared_ptr` owns what it points to. An object cannot have two owners, unless those owners have a prearranged agreement to co-operate, which shared pointers have with each other.

If you want to have `std::vector<Foo> data`, then pass around raw pointers (or references) to its elements, with the caveat that those pointers (or references) can become invalid if the `vector` is modified. This method is not the safest approach out there, but in some circumstances, it is good enough. *Alternatively, if elements are never removed from `data`, then you could pass around indices into `data` instead of pointers.*

If you want to have `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> ptr_data` then use shared pointers – or weak pointers – in every container that lays claim to these objects. That is, `data` would also be a vector of `shared_ptr`s.

```
void addDataToVectors() 
{
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<Foo>(20);
    data.push_back(ptr);
    ptr_data.push_back(ptr);
}
```

If you play mix-and-match, you might as well play gas-and-matches.